# Understanding Rails ActionMailer coding

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer

I am bit confused about  ActionMailer coding.

A standard action mailer example

**app/mailers/example_mailer.rb**

```
class ExampleMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "from@example.com"

  def sample_email(user)
    @user = user
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Sample Email')
  end
end
```

**app/controllers/users_controller.rb**

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save

      # Sends email to user when user is created.
      ExampleMailer.sample_email(@user).deliver_now

      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

My questions are related to

```
ExampleMailer.sample_email(@user).deliver_now
```

1. How `ExampleMailer` access `sample_email` method without `ExampleMailer.new`? `sample_email` is not a class  method!
2. How `deliver_now` call `ExampleMailer` ?

I hope it is clear. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that `sample_email` is not a class method, it's an instance method. But `ExampleMailer` inherits from `ActionMailer::Base` that does some clever meta-programming.

When you call `ExampleMailer.simple_email` it doesn't find a class method, so that automatically calls the private method `method_missing`.

In `method_missing` it checks if the instance method exists, creates a mailer instance object (so it basically does the `.new` for you), calls the instance method on the mailer object, and then returns the object... and on that object, you called the `deliver_now` or `deliver_later` method since you specified those methods in your original line.  Basically the same as if you did...

```
my_mail_thing = ExampleMailer.sample_email(@user)
my_mail_thing.deliver_now
```

However, if ExampleMailer doesn't find the instance method, it falls back on the standard missing responses e.g. "NoMetihodError:: undefined method 'another_simple_email' for ExampleMail.:Class"

It's all pretty amazing.  You can read more about `method_missing` by googling the term, and you can experiment on your own classes.